# Classifying points within polygon, outside of polygon OR within buffer at polygon edge using R

Tags: shapefile, r, polygon, buffer, rstudio

I have two objects, a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`, "points" and a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, "world_buffer" (both +proj=utm +datum=WGS84). The `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` is the world's coastlines, found [here](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/shorelines/), with a 5 km buffer around it, computing using `gBuffer()`.

I am trying to classify the "points" as either within the polygon (land), within the buffer (coast), or outside of the buffer (ocean).

I have tried using st_intersection() to get the points within the buffer:

```
library(sf)
points_within_buffer <- st_intersection(points, world_buffer)
```

But this gives the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("st_intersection") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_intersection' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPointsDataFrame', 'SpatialPoints', 'Spatial', 'SpatialVector', 'SpatialPointsNULL')"
```

And the above code won't classify points on land or ocean anyway. I'm used to using `ArcMap` for spatial analyses but am trying to move to R.

Answer (score 5):

There are two sets of classes for spatial data in R, and you are mixing them. They do not mix.

The `sp` package provides the classes that start `Spatial....`, such as your `SpatialPointsDataFrame`. Then the `sf` package provides different classes for the same sort of data, and these are usually called "sf classes" or "spatial data frames".

You can't use functions designed for one class with objects of the other.

For example to compute a buffer on `sp` objects you use `rgeos::gBuffer(spdf,...)`. To do the same on an `sf` object you use `sf::st_buffer(sfdf,...)`.

The `sf` package and objects are newer and mostly much faster and better designed. If you can use them, use them.

There are conversion functions to go from one set of classes to another, but that's always going to be sub-optimal if you can do everything with one set of classes.

To convert your objects to `sf`, use `st_as_sf(points)` and `st_as_sf(world_buffer)` and then `st_intersection` should work on them. But you'll get back an `sf` object.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know this so this so this is helpful! Do you know how I would classify objects as either land, buffer (coast) or ocean? Even if I get the intersection to work, it will only give me the points that overlap with the buffer.

Comment: If it intersects buffer then its coast, if it intersects land but not buffer then its land, otherwise its ocean? Suggest you use `st_intersects` which is a test for intersection rather than returning a new geometry set.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I'm being clear on my understanding. I do not know how to define the intersect to look for these areas. I converted my objects to sf and ran st_intersects() but I get a large sgbp full of int(0)'s, and if I try plot(intersect), I get the error: Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'

Comment: You need to read the help page for `st_intersects`. There's examples. If you still can't work it out, write a new question here and simplify your example as much as possible, and include (or create in code) sample data.